# Родственность слов

Tags: этимология, словообразование, морфемика

Являются ли исторически однокоренными слова "каша" и "косить"? Кашу готовят из скошенного зерна.

Answer (score 1):

Зерно не косят, это вы придумали. Косят (да и то не обязательно) **колосья**.

Насчет родственности - это вряд ли. Ни фонетически, ни семантически слова на самом деле не связаны.

Оба слова - очень древние, думаю, что в те времена и косы-то современной (т.н. литовки) и не было, "зерно" жали. Серпами.

"Коса" в индоевропейских имеет предположительный семантический ряд со значениями, во-первых, связанными с "резать", "срезать", а, во-вторых, с "плечо" или "сгибать" - тут более чем вероятна связь с прилагательным "косой"

А "каша" - она и есть каша, слово самодостаточно, Присутствует во многих славянских.

Ничего общего, кроме случайного и отдаленного фонетического сходства, не просматривается.

Comment: Эх жаль, у меня в бумажном мультисловаре написано, что происхождение слова "каша" до конца не установлено. И я подумал, что "каша" произошло от "скашивать", ведь у них один и тот же корень.

Comment: Дмитрий, одинаковые написание и  звучание корней ещё не говорит о том, что это один и тот же корень. Изначально они могли сильно отличаться, со временем придя к одному виду и став омонимичными.